# how to define and print a list in apex class

Tags: salesforce

syntax for defining and printing a list in an apex class for a custom/standard object in sales force .

```
public class listpgm {
  list <integer>Teacher__c =new list();
}
```

Comment: Where you want to display the list..?Visualforce Page..?

Answer (score 0):

For `Standard Object`

```
List<Account> accs = new List<Account>();//Creating a List for Account Object.
```

Ex :

List accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'SomeName'];

For `Custom Object`

```
List<ObjectName__c> Cust_Object = new List<ObjectName__c>();//Creating a List for Custom Object.
```

It depends how you  want to display the list in User Interface.You can bind List to `<apex:repeat>`,`<apex:Pageblocktable>`,`<apex:datatable>`...and you can bind list to `<apex:SelectList>`.

[Check here](http://nanostuffs.com/Blog/?p=751) : Displaying the list in `Pageblocktable`.